# Adding a Grid Panel to the 1st tab of the Tab Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, extjs4.1

I have a GRID which works properly. Now I need to add this GRID to the first Tab Panel. How can I do that?

my code:

GRID.JS

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    xtype:'grid',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

TAB.JS

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            xtype:'grid'
        },
        {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html : 'Another one'
        }
    ],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

I have added the `xtype:grid` in GRID.JS and I am trying to access that Grid from TAB.JS in the 1st tab, but it is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xtype: 'grid'` - means `create standard Ext.grid.Panel and add it here`.

You have two options:

Create your grid and save it into variable.

```
var _grid = Ext.create('...', {...});

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    ...
    items: [
       _grid
    ]
});
```

Or, define your own class with new `xtype`

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   alias: 'widget.mygrid',
   ... 

});

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    ...
    items: [{
       xtype: 'mygrid'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Sorry sha, it was an accident.  I actually came back here to see why my reputation dropped a point.  It doesn't look like I can undo my downvote unless you edited your post.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left